# How to Delete Twilio Messaging Service Programatically

Tags: php, twilio

I have been dynamically creating messaging services for sms/mms messages through the Twilio API, and unbeknownst to me these services I have been creating programmatically have been saving and piling up. I thought they were only temporary, lasting the life of the request. But, no, we now have over 600 services showing in the Twilio dashboard, most of them having the same name.

Instead of having to go into the dashboard and manually delete each one at a time (There is no "check all" in the Twilio dashboard), can I delete these messaging services programmatically as easily as I created them?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services/api#delete-a-service-resource

Comment: Yikes, I have to delete them by Messaging Service SID? I can't delete them by service friendly name? This is going to make for a long day :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [fetch](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services/api#) all of them, filter by friendly name, and then [delete](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services/api#delete-a-service-resource) the ones you no longer need.

```php
$twilio->messaging->v1->services("MGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                      ->delete();
```

Comment: Once I got the hang of it, it was almost magical. Twilio is the best API, ever, and mostly because their documentation pages with the How To in different languages is the most comprehensible, and well-answered services on the Net.

Comment: We're super happy to hear this :)  Thanks a lot!